# Sum of Arithmetic progression problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, arithmetic, arithmetic-progressions

I have following progression:

> $2n+(2n-1)+\cdots+n$

which is equivalent to:

> $n+(n+1)+\cdots+2n$

The answer says:

> You match $2n-i$ with $n+i$ for all $i=0..n$ Therefore you have $(n+1)$ terms
>   of $3n$, so the sum of the $2$ exactly same sequence is $3n(n+1)$ and
>   therefore the sum of 1 sequence is $1.5n(n+1)$
>
> Or you can just apply the formula for the sum of Arithmetic
>   progression, please refer to the wiki page
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression

Thus, I tried applying sum of arithmetic progression since I need to make it "$1.5n(n+1)$". but when I apply sum of arithmetic progression, it gives me different result like "$\frac n2(2n+(n-1)*1) = 1.5n^2-0.5n$"

How can I get "$1.5n(n+1)$"?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please Use Mathjax

Comment: To correctly display formulas enclose them with dollar signs \$\$ see my edit to see how,for a bit more advanced tutorial for typing math on this site look at this tutorial [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sum of an artihmetic progression is (first term + last term)*(number of terms)/2.

Here :

- first term=n,
- last term=2n,
- number of terms=n+1

Applying the formula, $Sum=\frac{(n+2n)*(n+1)}{2}$ reaches your desired result...